# Update wordpress database using wordpress API and pure javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to update my database when someone clicks the orange buttons on my site https://tomcurphey.com
I used a few tutorials to learn WP API to get an add function working however I cannot get the update function to work?
Any suggestions on where I am going wrong?

Sorry I have been trying multiple things..
The code is calling from js/tom.js on line 523 the api code in functions.php on line 213.

You can find my code at https://github.com/Muppet-training/tom

Or if you could point me in the right direction..
I would really appreciate it!

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using WP API for this at all.

Consider adding an [ADMIN AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) call in the `functions.php`

Comment: I was thinking of doing it that way.. I just wanted to try doing it with the API